# When updating the Nano Ledger S firmware, do I need to re-authorize my Ledger S?

Tags: baking, ledger

I'm baking with a Ledger S. I just updated to the latest firmware, but the nano ledger S now says "No key authorized" when previously I was baking with it before the firmware update. How do I re-authorzie my Ledger Baking key? Also, do I need to do anything besides just re-authorizing the key?

Note: I was baking for weeks leading up to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-authorize the key using the below:

```
tezos-client authorize ledger to bake for <SIGNATURE>
```

Where signature is the name of the ledger, which you can bring up using:

```
tezos-client list connected ledgers
```

You most likely don't need to register the key again on the blockchain, unless your key has become inactive (you can check on tzscan). In case you do, you can register with the following:

```
tezos-client register key ledger_<...>_ed_0_0 as delegate
```